# Manifest merger failed on dependency com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to update my project to the lastest firebase versions but I got this error: 
Manifest merger failed :

```
Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:28:5-423:19 to override.
```

on `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'`

also my project has this dependencies from google and firebase would it effect?

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'

    //noinspection OutdatedLibrary
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'


    // Add dependency
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
```

and here gradle and google services versions

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update to `AndroidX`, the following dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
```

with the above version require your application to use AndroidX.

Comment: is it possible to do that without updating my project to android x, because this will effect other dependencies?

Comment: use the following version `16.5.0`

Comment: the main point of upgrading is to update the com.google.firebase:firebase-core to latest version because the old version used INSTALL_REFERRER which paused by google for a security reason I found in this link https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android  : No longer add the Android library com.google.firebase:firebase-core but use com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2 the core dependency included in it but I can't achieve that also if I use 16.5.0 for com.google.firebase:firebase-core it gives me ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.5.0

Comment: the version `16.5.0` is last analytics version before androidx. If it cant be used then you have to upgrade to androidx

Comment: if the answer helped you, please upvote it and mark it as correct, thank you

Comment: sorry if It's late I up-vote it now but not yet trying to upgrade to android x I will do that and if it works will accept the answer, anyway thank you for your answer :)